# How to run blocked Java on browser?

Tags: java, security, internet-explorer, google-chrome

When I try to run this Java on chrome I get this message:
[image]
I think this is somehow a security problem.
How to bypass this and allow Java to run?

I'm trying to run the VNC viewer from the link provided by VNC server.

Comment: Is this your own app or someone else's?

Comment: Generally you can't if it is a security problem...
Java is made to do some security checking as it is made to run to many devices via Internet (see applets)... 

To me it doesn't seem a security issue though... There is clearly an exception about a bad argument here. Where is the code?

Comment: Does it not come up with the "allow once | allow always" option at the top of the page? If it is your app I'd made sure you have your java applet embedded correctly and java initialized correctly in your code with no wildly open calls to anything that can result in security holes.

That in mind check your chrome://plugins/ to make sure java is up to date and enabled. If you're missing security updates it'll hangup often times. Chrome and Java don't really get along period because of the structure of chrome and how it tries to sandbox everything within its own runtime environment.

Comment: It's VNC Remote desktop application, I'm trying to run the VNC viewer from the link provided.

Comment: @JackMcE Yes, it come up with the "allow once | allow always" option at the top of the page. Do you have any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: @user3503851 There is no link to the VNC in your post. Are you using this VNC viewer as an applet for people to sign in and connect to their server/computer with VNC on it for control purposes or is it pre-destined to automatically connect to a specific URL/IP/Machine? Because the invalid URL error could be from java or an error in VNC. We really need more information.

Comment: @JackMcE I have a desktop that have VNC Server Enterprise 5 installed on. It gives me a link in order to be able to control my desktop from any other PC on the network.

Comment: **DID YOU EVER CLICK THE DETAILS BUTTON?** Invalid url string seems that tried to fetch a malformed URL (or URI) and that's why you got IllegalArgumentException. I got also problems with vnc applet due to the new security schema on the java.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a security problem, but probably a problem with the applet, but I could be wrong. I don't think there is much you could do to access if it were a security problem, but you can go to the java control panel (Start > Programs > Java > Configure Java) and then go to security, then lower it (it is probably on high) to something lower, and then try again,  and hope that it works after that. Hope that helps, but it looks like the problem might be with the applet.

Comment: Figures. It was worth a try. It is probably not security related.